How to obtain syntax highlight/coloring for Snakemake file?
The snakemake documentation show syntax highlighting of the Snakefile file, like in here

Can I obtain something like for the Snakefile in an IDE, e.g. PyCharm or VSC?
With PyCharm I have tried associating the Python file type also with files called Snakefile, but that also checks the syntax, and of course shows errors all over the place. I would like to get (configure) syntax highlights only, if possible.

There is the snakemake-fmt:

VSCode;
PyPi (can be used via CLI);
editor integration docs.

Update:
For PyCharm, there is the SnakeCharm plugin.

I think snakemake-fmt is for formatting/fixing, not syntax highlighting.

Thanks, @TroyComi, hmm, it seems to support the syntax highlighting. FWIW snakemake-fmt seems to depend on this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Snakemake.snakemake-lang

Oops, I stand corrected!  Though for pycharm I don't see a mention of syntax highlighting.  Do you know if the directions on the fmt repo result in syntax highlighting?

Nope, I haven't tried it in PyCharm. :) I was able to find this plugin called SnakeCharm: https://github.com/JetBrains-Research/snakecharm Will add to the answer.

I don't see a custom syntax highlighter for pycharm in the misc folder of snakemake.  Seems like pycharm custom syntax files are non-trivial, but you can open a feature request in the snakemake repo to ask for one.  I bet more people use IDEs instead of the current vim and nano options.
